# Large JSON response truncated from Azure API app (.NET Core)

Tags: .net, json, api, azure, asp.net-core

I have a standard .NET Core API Controller that returns JSON.

All works as designed but with larger data sets the response is being truncated.

I cannot work out (or find on Stackoverflow or elsewhere) how to increase the limit - presuming this is the cause.

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: did you try to setup maxJsonLength in web.config? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1151993/2833802 and maybe http://stackoverflow.com/a/3853785/2833802

Comment: I did try that. May have got a typo or something so will try again

Comment: Which version of MVC package are you using?

Comment: @Set: Question is about ASP.NET Core, the linked answer is for legacy ASP.NET which also uses web.config as settings file.

Comment: @MarkChidlow, Could you use the Fiddler to trace your result? And Would you like to share your json result size ?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and what seemed to fix it was setting the 'ReferenceLoopHandling' JSON setting:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => {
            options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        });
 ...
}
```